# Ubuntu 14 - Nginx - PHP5-fpm : installed phpmyadmin but 403 forbidden access

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04

Nginx and PHP5-FPM are installed and running well ...

# I can access both http://www.example.com and http://www.example.com/info.php

```
$ ls -la /var/www/html
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  868 Nov  1 08:16 index.html
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   21 Nov  1 08:13 info.php
```

I installed phpmyadmin and created a symlink to phpmyadmin files

```
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Nov  1 08:37 phpmyadmin -> /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

but trying to get  http://www.example.com/phpmyadmin  =>  I get a 403 Forbidden

using a symlink, I should not have to add anything related to phpmyadmin into my nginx.conf ... what could be missing ?

Update 1 :  adding  index.php to the uri brings the login panel

```
 http://www.example.com/phpmyadmin/index.php
```

what should I add to my default con file to get it directly ... I guess my try file is not valid ..
here is my default nginx site con file

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php, index.html index.htm;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ index.html index.php  =404;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /var/www/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

it's running fine after adding the following location :

```
     location /phpmyadmin {
       index index.php;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

I have added:

```
location /pma/ {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location ~ ^/pma(.+\.php)$ {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin$1;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; #OR fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/phpmyadmin$1;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
    }
}
```

So that when the user access the directory `/pma/` they get directed to the `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` which is a slightly 'safer' option too! As previously I was having the 403 error too!

But the main fix for the `403` error is actually implementing the line:

```
index index.html index.htm index.php;
```

Comment: instead of "location /pma/" change to "location /pma" so no need "/". It just make you confuse when typing url in browser... thanks ..

Comment: this worked for me but only after clearing the browser cache

Answer (score 7):

That's my solution for this issue:

**Step 1**: You should SSH and run command

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

**Step 2**: find block code

```
server {
  ....
}
```

and then insert before "}" of server block

```
    location /phpmyadmin {
            index index.php;
    }
```

It look like this

```
server{
       ...(your default)...
       location /phpmyadmin {
                index index.php;
       }
}
```

Hope this is your!

Answer (score 4):

to nginx.conf file or default ( ../sites-available/default )

```
location /phpmyadmin {
       root /usr/share/;
       index index.php index.html index.htm;
       location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
               try_files $uri =404;
               root /usr/share/;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
               fastcgi_index index.php;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       }
       location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
               root /usr/share/;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple things you could try. One is the [`disable_symlinks`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#disable_symlinks) directive:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    disable_symlinks off;
}
```

Another option would be to use an alias instead of a symlink:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, I tried it, bt always get the same error in log :  directory index of "/var/www/html/phpmyadmin/" is forbidden, ...

Comment: Do you have `index index.php` in your server block?

Comment: If I request   http://www.example.com/phpmyadmin/index.php THEN I get the login panel...    I have root /var/www/html;

        index index.php, index.html index.htm;
 in my server block ...

Comment: Are you using `try_files`? You could try appending index.php to it.

Comment: I have a try_files , but on the / location...  I don't have anything for the /phpmyadmin location ... just a symlink, should I need to add anything to my nginx con file ?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lose the comma and you're fine

> ```
>     index index.php, index.html index.htm;
> ```